# UI responsiveness on listbox ItemSelectionChanged() event

Tags: c#, responsive-design, selectionchanged

I'd like to enable a button if some Data is available:

```
private void myListBox_ItemSelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     downloadButton.Enabled = myList.SelectedItems.Cast<myClass.myObject>().Any(x => x.Data != null);
}
```

The problem is that the UI is not quite responsive, and behaves weirdly (sometimes when I click the selection does not get changed when I click and select a different element). I figured that this is because of that bit of code.

Any suggestion to speed things up?

Comment: Do the myList.SelectedItems.Cast<myClass.myObject>().Any(x => x.Data != null)  part in a background thread.

Comment: Not a bad idea, however a new thread will be started on every click (and selection changed)..?

Comment: Not if you have a threadpool. First measure how long that operation takes..normally that should not be an issue... for me it's a little bit strange that something like that causes problems.. But if you already measured that this line takes too long then either you have to do that operation on a different way, or just shift the code to a background thread (which again...should be in a threadpool). Btw what is this? WPF? Store app? ...?